Upload and download photos from the Postgresql database?
I am writing a bot on aiogram, I took PostreSQL as a DBMS. The database contains the product ID, photo, name, and description with price. I tried uploading the URL of the photo to the database, but when output, it is necessary that the URL is not output, but the image itself is output. Or is there another way to upload an image without a URL?
Important: images must be stored in a database
import psycopg2
import asyncpg
import asyncio
import aiogram
from aiogram import types


class BD1:


    def ss():
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",
                                    port=5432,
                                    database="postgres",
                                    user="postgres",
                                    password="135")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            print("Database opened successfully")
            # cur.execute("SELECT photo FROM proba")
            # ph = cur.fetchone()[0]
            # photo = types.InputFile(ph)

            # await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption='Check out this photo!')

            cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM perfumes""")
            query_results = cur.fetchall()
            # cur.execute("SELECT photo FROM proba ;")
            # photo = cur.fetchone()[0]
            #
            # # Сохранение изображения в файл
            # with open("image.jpg", "wb") as file:
            #     file.write(photo)
            text = '\n\n'.join(['\n\n'.join(map(str, x)) for x in query_results])
            return (str(text))

        except psycopg2.Error as e:
            print("Error connecting to database:", e)
        finally:
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
        # cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM perfumes""")
        # query_results = cur.fetchall()
        # text = '\n\n'.join([', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in query_results])
        # return (str(text))

handlers.py:
        @router.callback_query()
        async def callback_keyboard(callback: CallbackQuery):
            if callback.data == 'teas':
                await callback.answer()
                await callback.message.answer(BD1.ss())


What exactly is your question?

To store and retrieve images directly you need to handle binary data as (BLOB) and it can  be done by using bytea.

So i didn't get you question 100%, but i know you can store the images as a bytea type in the DB and concert in back in an image

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
